# Can HtmlUnit handle JavaScript redirects?

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

Instead of automatically following JavaScript redirects, can I force HtmlUnit to return the URL the JavaScript wants to redirect me to?

// context:

If there's 5 JavaScript redirects in a row, I can only see the URL of the page where it stopped - I can't view the 5 URLs it ran through.

Perhaps I can hook up the logger to a callback method to look for redirects? Not sure if this is possible, or how it would work..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding a WebWindowListener to the WebClient, and waiting for the webWindowContentChanged method to get called.

Comment: Yes, I did this and it worked fine.  Keep in mind that you're working with multiple threads (webWindowContentChanged method is called by different thread), and that if you have multiple redirects you may have to wait for each of them.